# .htacess - Redirect only if its android

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I need to auto open page in chrome. This code opens in mobile chrome without any problems.

```
RedirectMatch 301 id/(.*)$ intent://remoteurl.com/cancel.php?id=$1#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end
```

But need this work only if user is on Android. So I have tried this but it doesnt redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android) [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 ^id/(.*)$ intent://remoteurl.com/cancel.php?id=$1#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end
```

The problem is, this url scheme won't work if RewriteRule is used,

```
RewriteRule ^i/(.*)$ intent://remoteurl.com/cancel.php?id=$1#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end [R=301,L]
```

but works with redirectMatch 301. However, redirectMatch 301 doesn't work if
RewriteCond is used.
So what is the correct way to do that ?

(Similar questions have already been asked, however this is for different url scheme intent://)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the one of the following code for redirecting the user if he is visiting from mobile ....

**Using PHP:**

```
<?php
function isMobile()
{
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}
// If the user is on a mobile device, redirect them
if(isMobile())
{
    // Redirect to Some where ....
    header("Location: http://m.yoursite.com/");
}
?>
```

**Using .htaccess:**

- Code 1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|ipad|android|blackberry|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.m.yoursite.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://yoursite.com
```

- Code 2

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|android|blackberry|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.yoursite.com
```

Comment: Thanks. But I know these already, have you tried "intent://" url in RewriteRule ? It doesn't work somehow.

Comment: Forgot to add, the the redirect url is external.

Comment: Update: php header redirect is working with "intent://" so it solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Great. Good Luck.